# Flickering when drawing the background outside of the main loop

Tags: c++, sfml

Here's my CODE:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(300, 300), "The Problem");
int main()
{
    sf::Texture tX;
    tX.loadFromFile("Recursos/Fondo.png");
    sf::Sprite tXt(tX);
    renderWindow.draw(tXt);
    while (true) // main loop
    {
        renderWindow.display();
    }
}
```

`tX` is a large sprite (think: background), so I want to avoid redrawing it every frame.

When I try this, I get flickering, and I have no idea where it's coming from.

Comment: What kind of flickering? Like tearing? Try enabling v-sync.

Comment: I don't know exactly what type the flickering is, but is deleting and re-writing the sprite. This is exactly what happens: http://makeagif.com/i/tEl9xD

Comment: So the sprite flashes black?

Comment: yes  (12 char,ignore this)

Comment: Could you please add a gif/video of the flickering you're getting?

Comment: You should read the tutorials, especially the red boxes. [You're missing event handling](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/window-window.php#bringing-the-window-to-life), it's crutial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, simplified, pseudo:

```
Initialize();
Draw();
Loop {
    Display();
}
```

What you're doing is drawing the scene to a buffer (without clearing it first, by the way), and then displaying it in a loop (without redrawing anything).

I think the reason you have flickering is due to double-buffering (v-sync).
What ends up happening is that you drew to one buffer, but left the other one empty. When you display the active buffer, they get flipped (so the next time you display, it's an empty buffer).
You really should draw inside the loop.

---

Alternatively, you can disable multiple-buffering, or try drawing, displaying, drawing again, and then looping (so that you draw to both buffers, assuming there are only two).

Both solutions are not elegant.

If drawing the background really needs optimization, I'm afraid SFML won't give you that granularity. You might want to look in to OpemGL Stencil wizardry.

Comment: Thanks  (12 characters protection)

Comment: @BlackOHAWK 1. There's a reason for the limit. Don't actively bypass it if you have nothing to add. 2. Stackoverflow's way of saying "thanks" is an upvote. If the answer solves your problem, hit the checkmark to mark it as "accepted answer".

Comment: @IvanRubinson Is it correct to think that the thing that we draw on in sfml is a slate with two sides, we draw on one side and show that side with `window.display()` ?, then in next loop we draw on the other side and show that side with the next `window.display()` ?

Comment: @jeea that's double-buffering, yes.